# Does my app have some sort of wall I can post to?

Tags: php, facebook

I have an app which posts user's activity on my website to Facebook ('Username read an article', etc).  It's also used for login at that site (Connect).  What I'd also like to do is somehow notify each user of the daily updates the site makes in their newsfeed.

I toyed with the idea of posting to each user's stream daily, but that's untenable - that can't scale beyond a couple thousand users with the resources I have.

What I'd like to do is something like a page.  Everyone who is a user of my app gets something in their newsfeed notifying them of an update, much like likers of pages do, however I don't want to have users add the app *and* like a separate page to get the updates, I just want all users of the app to also get these updates.

**EDIT:**

It looks like Apps do have feeds that one can post to.  I used this method, and was given a return value implying success (a post id):

```
$facebook->api('/<APP_ID>/feed', 'POST', array( 'link' => "http://example.com", 'message' => 'Example message'));
```

However, I've no idea where this message should show up, and it didn't show up in my personal newsfeed (I've authorized the app in question on my personal account).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See this blog post: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611 - the connection you're referring to is deprecated and will shortly be removed - it should already be gone but it looks like it's held on for another few weeks

Comment: So what are the alternatives then?  Running a page in parallel?  Posting to individual user's streams?  They seem like inelegant solutions.

Comment: There's an option in the app settings to create a page for your app; which will have a 'go to app' button, etc. Then publish to it as you would any other page and the page's fans will see the posts - no different from your point of view to how things worked with the old app profile pages, just one additional step in the app settings

Comment: Hmm,I'd looked and looked for such a thing and couldn't find it, but yeah, there it is.  Thanks.  But will people how auth the be automatic likers of that page?  Is the best I can do to add a like button for that page from within the app canvas?  Thanks again.

Comment: Yep, that's how you would have obtained fans of the old app profile page too - there never was a way to automatically add the app's users as fans of the app's page

Comment: Well, I guess that'll have to do.  Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

check out the following link that will help to understand the `$facebook->api()` more briefly with examples http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/